# Do closed questions and other items count toward fulfilling your commitment?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, committment

As of yesterday, I had six questions and four answers, and the sum of the two is ten. That is versus the required ten questions and/or answers to make up a fulfilled commitment. (Actually I had a fifth answer that I deleted because it was a "drag" on my reputation on the site, but that's "water under the bridge.")

Today, one of my questions was put on hold. Does that question still count toward the ten? Or will I have to replace it with another question or answer to fulfill my commitment?

**Edit:** Do contributions on meta count toward fulfilling your commitment? I can think of at least one person who I fear is in danger of not fulfilling the (10 post) commitment requirement on the main site, but who has been very active on meta. (If you combine his beta and meta posts, they are more than ten).

More to the point, my current understanding is that if you have been "active" during the private beta by editing, commenting, or on meta, the beta quota can be reduced BELOW ten posts during private beta, which might allow him to "qualify." (If you don't receive a "fulfilled" badge shortly after public beta begins, you ARE held to at least 10.)

Comment: The point of participation in the private beta is not to game the beta badge. Focus instead on expert-level content and expert-level community.

Comment: @Energy Numbers. I take my commitments seriously. I actually thought of withdrawing when it became apparent that my contributions on the site were not of the highest quality. But that is hard to do once the private beta began. So my second idea was to fulfill my quota, and "cap" my contributions at 10, leaving more room for others on the site. That's why I deleted my "eleventh" (the fifth answer).

Comment: Not fulfilling the commitment is no problem. It is much more important to keep the quality up. Creating this community is serious voluntary work.

Comment: @TomAu while it's kind of you to think of me, so far as I'm concerned my interests lie in having a thriving, useful Earth Sciences site in a year's time - not in playing games with my stats. If this means I can't commit to more than another one or two sites for a few months, so be it - it's not as though I have time to be active on very many!